# Replace a class javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a script that generates a table, and each box has an id from 0 to 99 (because there are 100 boxes)
Every other box contains a different background. (every other box contains the class "case1" and the others "case2")
I would like, by randomly generating 20 numbers (from 0 to 99) to replace the boxes that contain the numbers I just generated by a different class (which would be "case3")

My code:

```js
function generateMap() { // Generate the table
  var Y = 10;
  var X = 10;
  var v = -1;
  var table = document.getElementById('gameTable');
  for (var r = 0; r < Y; r++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var c = 0; c < X; c++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell.setAttribute('id', v + 1);
      cell.setAttribute('class', 'cell ' + ((c + r) % 2 ? 'case1' : 'case2'));
      v++;
    }
  }

}
generateMap();

function insertBarrier() {
  var caseBarrier = new Array(20);
  for (var i = 0; i < caseBarrier.length; i++) {
    caseBarrier[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
  console.log(caseBarrier);
}

insertBarrier();
```

```html
<table id="gameTable" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; "></table>
```

The generateMap function works (it builds an array of 100 squares)
And for now, my insertBarrier function only generates an array containing 20 random numbers because I do not know how to replace the boxes containing the id corresponding to the numbers generated by the class "case3"

Thanks :(

Comment: Use `<Element>.classList.add('yourClass')` or `<Element>.classList.remove('yourClass')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you generating barriers before the map generation then set the corresponding classes during generating the map.

To generate barriers appropriately, make the full array of the cells numbers, shuffle it (using e.g. [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm), then cut array to the desired length.

```js
function generateMap() { // Generate the table
  var table = document.getElementById('gameTable');
  var Y = 10;
  var X = 10;
  var v = 0;

  var barriers = Array.from(Array(X * Y).keys())
    .map((e, i, a) => {
      var r = Math.random() * (X * Y - i - 1) + i + 1 | 0;
      [e, a[r]] = [a[r], e];
      return e;
    });
  barriers.length = 20;

  for (var r = 0; r < Y; r++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var c = 0; c < X; c++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell.id = cell.textContent = v++;
      cell.className = barriers.indexOf(+(c + '' + r)) > -1 ?
        'barrier' : (c + r) % 2 ? 'case1' : 'case2';
    }
  }
}
generateMap();
```

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

td {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  font-size:8px
}

.case1 {
  background: #cef
}

.case2 {
  background: #fec
}

.barrier {
  background: #f42
}
```

```html
<table id="gameTable"></table>
```

Comment: Omg! Thanks you! ♥

Comment: @THOMASCorentin, happy to help!